# how to implement wifi direct between windows 10 and linux (ubuntu)

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, wifi-configuration

I'm trying to establish **WIFI DIRECT** connection between windows 10 and Linux (ubuntu).
I'm following steps as per the below link.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-implement-wifi-direct-between-windows10-and/4ca49250-38a0-4327-9f39-47284a9af800.

My Linux side configuration file

```
root@var-som-mx6:~# cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf 
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1
device_name=LZ_50
device_type=2-0050F204-1
p2p_listen_reg_class=81
p2p_listen_channel=1
p2p_oper_reg_class=81
p2p_oper_channel=1
p2p_go_intent=1
p2p_no_group_iface=1

network={
    ssid="test"
    psk="test@123"
}

network={
    ssid="DIRECT-b3"
    bssid=2c:6b:7d:0c:73:62
    psk="Fcvpxj3L"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP
    auth_alg=OPEN
    mode=3
    disabled=2
}
```

I can **successfully communicate** between Linux to Linux using wifi direct.
Now when I trying to establish communication between Windows and Linux. it is failing and its logs are as per below.

```
     <3>RX-PROBE-REQUEST sa=4c:34:88:38:5f:50 signal=-66 
    <3>RX-PROBE-REQUEST sa=4c:34:88:38:5f:50 signal=-65 
    <3>RX-PROBE-REQUEST sa=4c:34:88:38:5f:50 signal=-66 
    <3>RX-PROBE-REQUEST sa=4c:34:88:38:5f:50 signal=-70 
    <3>RX-PROBE-REQUEST sa=4c:34:88:38:5f:50 signal=-67 
    <3>RX-PROBE-REQUEST sa=4c:34:88:38:5f:50 signal=-68 
    <3>RX-PROBE-REQUEST sa=4c:34:88:38:5f:50 signal=-67 
    <3>RX-PROBE-REQUEST sa=4c:34:88:38:5f:50 signal=-66 
    <3>RX-PROBE-REQUEST sa=4c:34:88:38:5f:50 signal=-67 
    <3>RX-PROBE-REQUEST sa=4c:34:88:38:5f:50 signal=-66 
    <3>RX-PROBE-REQUEST sa=4c:34:88:38:5f:50 signal=-65 
    <3>WPS-ENROLLEE-SEEN 4c:34:88:38:5f:50 c696bebc-ff55-4051-aac8-d19cf290002b 1-0050F200-0 0x11e8 0 0 [DESKTOP-KM641DF] <3>RX-PROBE-REQUEST sa=4c:34:88:38:5f:50 signal=-60 
    <3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED 4e:34:88:38:5f:4f 
    <3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=1 
    <3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED 4e:34:88:38:5f:4f 
    <3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=1 
    <3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=14122 method=254 
    <3>WPS-REG-SUCCESS 4e:34:88:38:5f:4f c696bebc-ff55-4051-aac8-d19cf290002b 
    <3>WPS-SUCCESS 
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE 4e:34:88:38:5f:4f 
    <3>WPS-ENROLLEE-SEEN 4c:34:88:38:5f:50 c696bebc-ff55-4051-aac8-d19cf290002b 1-0050F200-0 0x11e8 0 0 [DESKTOP-KM641DF] 
<3>RX-PROBE-REQUEST sa=4c:34:88:38:5f:50 signal=-58
```

**1) is my connection steps are correct?**

**2) is my configuration file is correct?**

Thank you for your time!!